# How to check Session Id upon calling application context

Tags: java, jsp, session, struts2

I have a doubt in implementing the session management, I am using Struts 2 in my web application.

When ever I enter `localhost:8080/WarFileName` it will open the file which is in the welcome file list of `web.xml`.

Please find my `web.xml` below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <description>ServletContextListener</description>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.framework.dbconnector.PersistenceAppListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <display-name>My App</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Well I know there will be a unique session id that will be generated upon first action getting called. I know that we can write interceptors which are called before actions where we can perform necessary checks. But I am not getting what to do when user puts the context path in the url like `localhost:8080/WarFileName`

So I want to know is there a way where I can call a action and check whether there is any session id exists on the next time when I enter `localhost:8080/WarFileName`

Currently issue in my application is even though use has logged in to the application, if I open a new tab and again put `localhost:8080/WarFileName` it is taking me to `index.jsp`.

Comment: And where do you want to redirect logged user if a new tab is opened with `localhost:8080/WarFileName` url?

Comment: I want to send him to Home Page. Like gmail if you are loggen in one tab and in next tab if u put www.gmail.com it automatically takes yoou to inbox.

Comment: So create a S2 interceptor and check if user is logged or not and return different results based on it.

Comment: i have created a interceptor which checks whether the user is logged in. But interceptor is called only before calling the action class like http://localhost:8080/WarFileName/someAction.action  If user puts http://localhost:8080/WarFileName/ in new tab, it will go to welcome file list and take him to login.jsp again

Comment: Then your problem is not with session. You should redirect to action from your welcome page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the welcome file you can redirect to the action that you should map to the URL, like `localhost:8080/WarFileName/myaction`. You can see the example [How to remove the action suffix extension in Struts 2](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/how-to-remove-the-action-suffix-extension-in-struts-2) (a little bit outdated already). You can also follow the [Hello World using Struts2](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/hello-world-using-struts2.html).

`index.jsp`:

```
<% response.sendRedirect("myaction"); %>
```